# Fixed Bootstrap Navbar Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position, navbar

I am trying to make it so that when I scroll down a page, my navbar is fixed at the top, I have tried so many different things and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Please see my code below for the nav.

```css
.navbar {
  padding: .8rem;
}

.navbar-nav li {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Navigation-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills ml-auto">
        <li class=nav-item active>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class=nav-item>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        </li>
        <li class=nav-item>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutme">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class=nav-item>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ahh awesome, I now have the problem of when scrolling. There appears to be certain point during the scroll where the nav bar hides itself? It seems to happen when reaching either a certain height on a page or when it hits the jumbotron/gallery.

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#placement). There is no `navbar-fixed-top`.. it's just `fixed-top`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.navbar {
  padding: .8rem;
}

.navbar-nav li {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Navigation-->
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills ml-auto">
        <li class=nav-item active>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class=nav-item>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        </li>
        <li class=nav-item>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutme">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class=nav-item>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div style="height: 5000px; background-color: red; width: 500px;"></div>
```

The navbar can have the class [`.sticky-top`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/) added to it in order to easily fix it to the top of the page. [Support](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) for this is widespread, with the exclusion of Internet Explorer. As an alternative, `fixed-top` can be used, but this may cause some overlapping issues if not supplemented by additional CSS.

A solid red `div` element has been included in order to make the page large enough to scroll through.

Comment: Hi StardustGogeta

Thanks so much this has helped a lot, but the problem i have now is that when i scroll down the page, as soon as i hit what looks like a jumbotron/container for my gallery or a certain height down the page, my navbar then hides and moves up? 

any ideas?

Comment: Hello @OliverStott! Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: HI yes this has solved the issue, i have developed a new one though but i can raise another question :)

Comment: Alright, thank you @OliverStott! Please upvote / accept this answer to close the question if it is resolved. Also, it is considered bad practice to post a follow-up question as an answer. Do not hesitate to simply add a separate question. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, sorry im very new to stack overflow. I will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

I have now developed the following issue, here is my full HTML.

When i scroll i seem to be losing the toolbar when it reaches a certain point in the document?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Unique Portraits</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css">
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="50">

<!--Navigation-->
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills ml-auto">
        <li class=nav-item active>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class=nav-item>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        </li>
        <li class=nav-item>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#aboutme">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class=nav-item>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Image SLider & Indicators -->
 <div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner" id="home">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/warm.jpg" >
    </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/landscape2.jpg">
    </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/river.jpeg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1 class="display-2">ALIAS PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
        <h3>My Journey Through Nature...</h3>
        <div class="showcase-buttons">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg mr-1">VIEW DEMO</button> -->
        <a href="#gallery"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">VIEW GALLERY</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>

  <!-- Arrows -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next btn-lg" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>

<!-- Jumbotron -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row jumbotron">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <p class="lead ml-5 mr-5">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has </p>
      <a href="#aboutme"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg text-center">Find out more</button></a> 
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="container gallery" id="gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 " id="cols">
      <a href="img/yellow.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="img/yellow.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 " id="cols">
      <a href="img/yellow.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="img/yellow.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 " id="cols">
      <a href="img/yellow.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="img/yellow.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 " id="cols">
      <a href="img/yellow.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="img/yellow.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 " id="cols">
      <a href="img/yellow.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="img/yellow.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 " id="cols">
      <a href="img/yellow.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="img/yellow.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 " id="cols">
      <a href="img/yellow.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="img/yellow.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 " id="cols">
      <a href="img/yellow.jpeg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="img/yellow.jpeg" class="img-fluid rounded"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- About -->
<div class="container-fluid about" id="aboutme">
  <div class=row padding>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 text-light text-center ">
      <h2 class="display-3 mt-4">A bit about me</h2>
      <p class="lead ml-5 mr-5">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has</p>
      <a href="#contact"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg m-1 mb-4">Why not get in touch?</button></a>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 aboutimg">
       <img src="img/landscapeold.jpeg">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Connect -->
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row jumbotron text-center m-0">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h2 class="display-3">Connect</h1>
  </div>
<div class="col-12 social padding">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="https://plus.google.com/up/?continue=https://plus.google.com/people" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
</div>
</div>  
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid padding text-center" id="contact">
    <div class="row text-light pt-4">
      <div class="col-6 addresscol">
        <hr class="light">
        <div>
        <p><i class="fa fa-envelope mr-3 mt-3 icon offset-4"></i>email@emaildomain.com </p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-phone mr-3 icon offset-4"></i>+12 34567 891</p>
        <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker mr-4 icon offset-4"></i>123 Same Street</p>
          <div>
        <p><i class="offset-4 mr-5"></i>County</p>  
        <p><i class="offset-4 mr-5"></i>Town</p>  
        <p class="pml"><i class="offset-4 mr-5 mb-1"></i>Postcode</p>   
          </div>
        </div>        
        <a href="dummyresume.rtf"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg mt-4 offset-">Download Résumé</button></a>
      </div>


<!-- Start of Form -->
<div class="col-6">
  <h2 class="pb-3 align-centre display-4"><i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i>
      Drop a Line
  </h2>
<div>
  <h4 class="display-5 formpadding">
      Dont hesitate to get in touch
  </h4>
</div>
<div data-form-type="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 formpadding">
       <input type="text" class="form-control input formfirst" name="name" data-form-field="Name" placeholder="Your Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 formpadding">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input formphone" name="phone" data-form-field="Phone" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 formpadding" data-for="email">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input" name="email" data-form-field="Email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 formpadding" data-for="message">
        <textarea class="form-control input" name="message" rows="3" data-form-field="Message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-btn col-md-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <button href="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-form">SEND MESSAGE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
 </div>
</div> 

<!-- End of Form -->
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="container-fluid copyright">
  <hr class="bg-light">
      <p class="lead">&copy; domainname.com</p>
  </div>
</footer>

<!-- JavaScript's -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an answer, post a new question and you can add link of your current question to that one. So people will get idea about what's going on.

Comment: Few people will take a look at your question as it already has a correct answer.